# PeerJS Auto Reconnect

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs

I have recently developed a web app using PeerJS, and am trying to add reconnect functionality.

Basically, my app works by someone creating a *server* that *clients* then connect to. The server person can control what the hosts are doing but its basic two way communication.

If a client disconnects they simply reconnect and it works normally. However if the server user refreshes the page, or their computer crashes then they need to be able to re-establish control over the clients.

The start of this is by regaining the original connection ID and peer api ID, which is fine and easy as they are stored in a database and assigned a unique ID the server user can use to query them. Then to enable the client to reconnect I do this upon close:

```
// connection is closed by the host involuntarily...
conn.on('close', function() { 

    // if the clients connection closes set up a reconnect request loop - when the host takes back control
    // the client will auto reconnect...

    connected = false;
    conn = null;

    var reconnect_timer = setInterval(function () {

        console.log('reconnecting...'); // make a fancy animation here...
        conn = peer.connect(connectionid, {metadata: JSON.stringify({'type':'hello','username':username})});    

        // upon connection
        conn.on('open', function() { // if this fails need to provide an error message... DO THIS SOON      
            // run the connect function...
            connected = true;
            connect(conn);      
        });

        // didnt connect yet
        conn.on('error', function(err) {
            connected = false;
        });

        if(connected === true) {
            clearInterval(reconnect_timer);
        }

    }, 1000);

});
```

This appears to work, as on the server end the client looks like they have reconnected - the connect function has fired etc. However messages cant be sent between, and the client console says:

```
Error: Connection is not open. You should listen for the `open` event before sending messages.(…)
```

Where the 'open' event is shown as having been listened to above...

I hope this is clear - any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

So in the end to create an auto reconnect script, I simply dealt with the client end of things, ensuring the server was set to the same api_key (for cloudservers) and key:

```
peer = new Peer(return_array.host_id, {key: return_array.api_key});
```

and then having the client, upon connection closing:

```
// connection is closed by the host involuntarily...
conn.on('close', function() { 
    // if the clients connection closes set up a reconnect request loop - when the host takes back control
    // the client will auto reconnect...

    peer.destroy();     // destroy the link
    connected = false;  // set the connected flag to false
    conn = null;        // destroy the conn
    peer = null;        // destroy the peer

    // set a variable which means function calls to launchPeer will not overlap
    var run_next = true;

    // periodically attempt to reconnect
    reconnect_timer = setInterval(function() { 
        if(connected===false && run_next===true) {
            run_next = false;   // stop this bit rerunning before launchPeer has finished...
            if(launchPeer(false)===true) { 
                clearInterval(reconnect_timer); 
            } else run_next == true;
        }       
    }, 1000);

});
```

Where launch peer will attempt to launch a new peer. To ensure continuity the new id from the client replaces the old id from the client and everything is a smooth takeover. The hardest part in the end was having the "setInterval" only fire once which is achieved (badly...) through use of boolean flags.

Thanks to anybody who read and thought how they could help :)

Comment: you can use `setTimeout` instead